# how to register onClick and onDoubleClick event from same JSX element in React Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

Is there a proper , established way to register either User permormed single click or double click on same JSX element inside of `Function` component. After reading articles on stackOverflow and watching youtube, the easiest solution for beginner like me was to create custom hook - `useClickHook`, and to use callback inside `setTimeout` api. In App component I'm using useEffect hook,
`clickHook` value is inside of array of dependencies. On first render its `0` , after first click = `1` , if doubleClick = `2`; inside of If() statement in useeffect - console.log() reperesents function to be invoked. and after i'm setting `clickHook` value back to default `0`.

Here is what I coded (minimal reproducible example)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useClickHook = (detail) => {
    const [clickDetail, setClickDetail] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setClickDetail(detail)
        }, 200);
        
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }, [detail]);

    return clickDetail;
}
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { useClickHook } from './ClickHook';

function App() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(0);
  const clickHook = useClickHook(click);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (clickHook === 1) {
      console.log('single click')
    }

    if (clickHook === 2) {
      console.log('double click')
    }

    setClick(0);
  },[clickHook])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Hello World
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          setClick(e.detail);
        }}
        onDoubleClick={(e) => {
          setClick(e.detail);
        }}
      >
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How to improve it?
Will be glad for every suggestions.

Edited!!!

So one way to improve is simple to remove onDoubleClick event handler from button JSX element .
Following code can be safely deleted

```
onDoubleClick={(e) => {
  setClick(e.detail);
}}
```

Thus , on `double click` setClick will be called only twice , not 3 times like in example proposed originaly , and the rest will be done by the custom hook as before.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can already do this in React with no special code required.

[Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui5-react-final-form-datepicker-forked-2570rv?file=/src/Demo.tsx)

```
export default function Demo() {
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.detail);
    switch (event.detail) {
      case 1: {
        console.log("single click");
        break;
      }
      case 2: {
        console.log("double click");
        break;
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Double click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I made myself not clear in the question , for what I'm sorry.
The question was how to trigger  function `console.log('some text')` depending on e.detail only once. In your proposed case , onDoubleClick , single click will be also triggered , something which I need to be prevented. But your answer made me realize that I can also drop onDoubleClick event handler from the code.

Comment: @PaulGutsal I just figured you could put the code you want to run for single click under case 1, and the double click code for case 2. Using setTimeout and creating React states to track clicks is both unnecessarily complicated and fraught with the potential for bugs. So I guess the real question is WHY you want to do what you want to do? What is the behavior you want to avoid?